# **Q:How can we infer $\hat{J}_\pm |\alpha,\beta>$ is proportional to $|\alpha,\beta+1>$ from 5.33 and 5.34? please explain in detail.**

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators

[image]

**Q:How can we infer  $\hat{J}_\pm |\alpha,\beta>$ is proportional to $|\alpha,\beta+1>$ from 5.33 and 5.34? please explain in detail.**

Reference : Page No:287, *Quantum Mechanics Concepts and Applications* by Zettili,2E

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please note that questions should be conceptual and not about homework or checking calculations.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I don't think this is about verifying calculations, but rather conceptual understanding of why the result holds. But that's just IMHO.

Comment: @Yoni Your opinion is as valid as mine but as phrased the question IMO has no conceptual contents: the answer is already in (5.33).

Answer (score 0):

The trick in 5.33 is often used for the purpose of showing what one operator does when you know the commutation relations with another operator that you are familiar with.

In 5.33 you first apply commutation relations with $J_z$ so that you can use it to extract an eigenvalue: $\hbar\beta$. The second term is just a scalar constant. Now that both of the terms are in the form of a constant times $J_\pm$, commutation is free of charge and you get the result of 5.33.

Comparing LHS=RHS, you can see why they say $J_\pm|\alpha,\beta>$ is an eigenstate for $J_z$, since $J_z$ did its business yet the ket stayed the same.

You know that the eigenstates of $J_z$ are exactly the projections of the angular momentum on $\hat z$, so it must be that $J_\pm|\alpha,\beta>$ has a projection component that is an eigenstate of $J_z$. But you saw that the extracted eigenvalue was $\beta + 1$, therefore $J_\pm|\alpha,\beta>$ must be proportional to $|\gamma,\beta+1>$ where $\gamma$ is still unknown.

To find $\gamma$ you want to do the same trick with an operator for which $\gamma$ is an eigenstate, and this of course is $J^2$, and this is exactly what was done in 5.34.

Finally, note that you only get proportionality relations, because all you care about are the eigenvalues. But getting the actual constant of proportionality is just a matter of normalization, which I assume is the next part of the text.

EDIT:

1. If we have $J_z|\psi>=\lambda |\psi>$, this means that $|\psi>$ is some eigenstate of $J_z$.
2. In order to identify $|\psi>$ with the familiar $|l,m>$ basis (or $|\alpha,\beta>$), all we have to do is to write $|\psi>$ in the form $|\alpha,\lambda>$. This is because we got $\hbar\lambda$ as the eigenvalue, and we know how $J_z$ operates, and we know how eigenstates of $J_z$ look like.
3. Now try to think of the ket: $\left(J_\pm|\alpha,\beta>\right)$ as this $|\psi>$. Eq. 5.33 shows (using commutation relations) that it is indeed an eigenstate of $J_z$, with $\lambda = \hbar (\beta\pm1)$. So from the above discussion we have that the ket: $\left(J_\pm|\alpha,\beta>\right)$ must be in the form $|\gamma,\beta\pm1>$, while at the moment we don't know what $\gamma$ is.
4. Finally, eq. 5.34 does exactly the same as 5.33, only with an operator for which $\alpha$ is an eigenstate, namely: $J^2$. So same as before, we realize that $\gamma=\alpha$.

Comment: Please explain simply, I am not understanding.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is this better? If not, which step is the problem?